# @SessionScoped beans CDI using Bootsfaces/Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, cdi, bootsfaces, session-scope

I am currently working on a Maeven Project.

Problem 1: The user can log in easily, and the menu of the page changes accordingly. But as soon as a menu item is clicked on, the user is logged out.

Problem 2: The login bean returns null values ​​when I inject them into another bean.

The main menu was made with bootfaces.

Tests: with a Primefaces Menubar everything works fine.

Template.xml:

```
 `<div id="top">
    <ui:insert name="top">
        <h:form rendered="#{!login.isIsloggIn()}" >
            <b:navBar brand="Enjoy the Holiday" brandHref="#" 
  inverse="true">

            <b:navbarLinks>
                <b:navLink value="Home" icon="home" 
   outcome="/HomePage"/>
              <b:navLink value="About" href="#about"/>
              <b:navLink value="Contact" href="#contact"/>
            </b:navbarLinks>
           <b:navbarLinks pull="right">
            <b:navLink value="Sign Up" outcome="/Registrationpage"/>
            <b:navLink value="Login" outcome="/LoginPage"/>

            </b:navbarLinks>
          </b:navBar>
        </h:form>

        <h:form rendered="#{login.isIsloggIn()}">
             <b:navBar brand="Enjoy the Holiday" brandHref="#" inverse="true">
            <b:navbarLinks>
                <b:navLink value="Home" icon="home" outcome="/HomePage"></b:navLink>
              <b:navLink value="About" href="#about"></b:navLink>
              <b:navLink value="Contact" href="#contact"></b:navLink>
            </b:navbarLinks >
            <b:navbarLinks pull="right">

                <b:dropMenu value="Wilkommen 
   {login.GetUserNamebyEmail()}"  >
                    <b:navLink value="Profil" icon="user" 
    outcome="/Overviews/KundeOverview"></b:navLink>

                    <b:navLink value="Inbox" icon="envelope" href="#"> 
        </b:navLink>
                    <b:navLink></b:navLink>
                    <b:navLink header="Konto"></b:navLink>
                    <b:navLink value="Einstellung" icon="cog" href="#"> 
   </b:navLink>
                </b:dropMenu>
                <b:navLink value="Logout" icon="log-out"  outcome="# 
    {login.loggOut()}"></b:navLink>
                 </b:navbarLinks>
              </b:navBar>
        </h:form>
    </ui:insert>
```

`

Login.xhtml:

```
 <ui:define name="content">
     <b:container>
        <h:form styleClass="form-signin" prependId="false">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <b:inputText id="email" placeholder="Email address"  value="#{login.email}">
                <f:facet name="prepend">
                    <b:icon name="user" />
                </f:facet>
            </b:inputText>
            <b:inputText id="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" value="#{login.password}">
                <f:facet name="prepend">
                    <b:iconAwesome name="key" />
                </f:facet>
            </b:inputText>
            <b:selectBooleanCheckbox value="true" caption="remember me"/>
            <b:commandButton look="primary btn-block" value="Sign In"  icon="log-in" size="lg" action="#{login.loggIn()}"/>
        </h:form>
    </b:container>

</ui:define>
```

Login Bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
 public class Login implements Serializable{

@Inject
private AccountService accountService;

private Account account;

@Inject
private DataTestService datatestservice;



@Inject
private UserService userService;

private boolean isloggIn = false;

private String email ,password;

private String loggedUserEmail = null;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    System.out.println("PostConstruct");
}

@PreDestroy
public void preDestroy() {
    System.out.println("PreDestroy");
}
public String loggIn(){


    this.account = this.accountService.checkPassword(email, password);
    if(this.account == null){

       return  "Loginfailed";
    }else{

        this.isloggIn = true;
        this.loggedUserEmail = email;
         return  "Loginsuccess";
    }

}
```

The other Bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class KundenModel implements Serializable {

@Inject
private Login login ;

 @Inject
private AccountService accountService;

@Inject
private KundeService kundeService;

@PersistenceContext(unitName="EtHPU")
private E .....
```

No Erros in Output but I get the following warnings :

```
13:05:22,555 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-5) WELD-000146: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper is deprecated from CDI 1.1!

13:17:08,869 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (default task-7) WFLYWELD0052: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module org.jboss.jts. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi]
```

Comment: Is it `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` or `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`?

Comment: i use javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped

Comment: @YounesOualad You said Login returns null values ? Do you mean the Login bean is null ? Or do you mean that the values inside the bean are null ? Some stack trace showing the problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to implement a LoginService (RequestScoped) which has an injected UserSession or UserContext (SessionScoped) which ONLY holds information about logged in user without any injected beans. I was thinking about this because I don't know what happenes with a SessionScoped Bean after RequestScoped Injections are destructed.

Try it like:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
 public class UserContext implements Serializable{
 private boolean loggedIn;
 private String email;

....
}
```

and

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
 public class LoginService implements Serializable{

 @Inject
 private UserContext userContext;

   public String loggIn(){


    this.account = this.accountService.checkPassword(email, password);
    if(this.account == null){

       return  "Loginfailed";
    }else{

        userContext.setLoggedIn(true);
         userContext.setUserEmail(email);
         return  "Loginsuccess";
    }

  }

}
```